Bad results while doing linear regression
I was trying to do a multi variate linear regression using a set of data. I tried to predict the Y using the same set of X used to generate the regression coefficients. While the differences between the actual and predicted value were less (as they were expected to be) for a set of data, it is more for another set of data. The two datasets represent same set of parameters (same physical quantity). Did I do something wrong or what can I do to improve?
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
.....
.....
# Construct the design matrix
X = np.column_stack((tir1, tir1_z, bt_diff, bt_diff_z, bt_diff_sst, s_theta, np.ones_like(tir1)))

sst = np.array([i+273.15 for i in selected_buoy_sst])

# Fit the OLS model
model = sm.OLS(sst, X)
results = model.fit()

predicted_sst_same_data = results.predict(X)

# Calculate the difference between actual SST and predicted SST
difference = sst - predicted_sst_same_data`


# using a different data
X_n = np.column_stack((tir1, tir1_z, bt_diff, bt_diff_z, bt_diff_sst, s_theta, np.ones_like(tir1)))
sst = skin_temp_array
# Fit the OLS model
model = sm.OLS(sst_n, X_n)
results = model.fit()

# Print the summary of the regression results
print(results.summary())

predicted_sst_same_data = results.predict(X)

# Calculate the difference between actual SST and predicted SST
difference = sst - predicted_sst_same_data


I can upload the data if needed. Does it depend on my x and Y values?
Edit: I have uploaded the required files.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JGG_KPYZAEV20DuRopJBNSIBWtfWW5MT/view?usp=sharing
Here x.npy and y.npy is the first set of data and x1.npy and y1.npy is the second data.

what's your R² and RMSE? The residual plot is not very easy to read if we do not understand the units of the difference and how significant they are. Uploading the data can help us help you further...

@TinoD I have uploaded the relevant files.

i can't see any data

@TinoD sorry for the miscommunication. The data files were not uploaded. Now it is there. Thanks for the support.
